# Problems with formula to output a triangle waveform in Java

Tags: java, algebra, waveform

I got my wave file creator working and I split it into three classes, I also made a sinewave generator that inherits from an abstract class called waveform and I can export 8 and 16 bit mono or stereo sine waves. I am trying to make a class called TriangleWave Generator to output a triangle wave tone, but I can't get the algebra from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave#, the first formula, to work. It will only export the highest harmonic stated and not blend them together with the fundamental

Sample length: length in seconds
point: individual sample
amp limit: the highest position possible
harmonics: the number of harmonics to use to make the waveform 1 = fundamental, 2 = 1st overtone, 3 = 2nd overtone.......
frequency: fundamental frequency (Middle C = 261.63)
sample rate = 44100; (CD quality)
triangle Samples array: sample data

This is my code

```
public class TriangleGenerator extends Waveform {
    
    // constants
    public static final int HARMONIC_COUNT = 16;

    // instance variabls
    int harmonics;
    int[] triangleSample;
    int addCount;

    // constructor
    public TriangleGenerator(double amplitude, double frequency, int bitRate, double duration, int harmonics) {
        super(amplitude, frequency, bitRate, duration);
        // sample data
        triangleSample = new int[sampleLength];
        calculateAmpLimit();
        this.harmonics = harmonics;
    }

    // one arg cunstructor
    public TriangleGenerator(double frequency) {
        this(AMPLITUDE, frequency, BIT_RATE, DURATION, HARMONIC_COUNT);
    }

    // no args constructor
    public TriangleGenerator() {
        this(AMPLITUDE, FREQUENCY, BIT_RATE, DURATION, HARMONIC_COUNT);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] generateWaveForm() {
        
        // generate the actual waveform
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleLength; i++) {
            point = (int)(ampLimit * ((8 / Math.pow(Math.PI, 2)) * sumnate(harmonics - 1, Math.pow(-1, addCount))
                    * Math.pow(harmonics, -2) * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * frequency * harmonics * i / SAMPLE_RATE)));
            triangleSample[i] = point;
        }

        // return the sample data
        return triangleSample;
    }
    
    public double sumnate(int n, double adder) {
        double sum = 0;
        
        for (addCount = 0; addCount <= n; addCount++) {
            sum += adder;
        }
        
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `sin` to do this rather than produce the straight lines directly by a linear formula? There is an advantage in using `sin` in that you don't get harmonic distortion from aliasing, but if that's an issue then you can oversample. The issue is that `sin` is much slower than basic arithmetic.

Comment: I want to adjust how mellow and bright the triangle wave sounds. For example, a Triangle wave with just the 1st and 3rd harmonics will sound like an organ Tibea, whereas one with more harmonics will sound more like a flute.

Comment: How would you make a triangle wave using a linear formula? I tried this in another post but the waveform gets too sharp. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61009312/problem-with-formula-to-output-a-triangle-waveform-using-linear-aliasing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the formula for the [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave#Harmonics):

[image]

the mode number `n` is dependent on the harmonic label `i`:

[image]

This means that it must also be summed over the components

[image]

which doesn't happen in the current implementation. One possible implementation is:

```
public int[] generateWaveForm() {
    for (int t = 0; t < sampleLength; t++) {
        triangleSample[t] = (int)(ampLimit * 8.0 / Math.pow(Math.PI, 2.0) * getDataPoint(t, N));
    }
    return triangleSample;
}

private double getDataPoint(int t, int N) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++) {
        sum += getHarmonicShare(t, i);
    }
    return sum;
}

private double getHarmonicShare(int t, int i) {
double n = 2.0 * i + 1.0;
    return Math.pow(-1.0, i) * Math.pow(n, -2.0) * Math.sin(2.0 * Math.PI * frequency * (t / SAMPLE_RATE) * n);
}
```

Here `t`, `i`, `n` and `N` correspond to the values from the formula. `frequency` denotes the frequency. The remaining values correspond to the parameters of the posted code.

The curve reaches up to the value `sampleLength / SAMPLE_RATE`. The period is `1 / frequency` and there are `(sampleLength / SAMPLE_RATE) * frequency` periods in the displayed frame.

*Example:*

```
sampleLength:   500
ampLimit:       100.00
SAMPLE_RATE:  44100.00
frequency:      261.63

sampleLength / SAMPLE_RATE:               0.0113378685
1 / frequency:                            0.0038221916
(sampleLength / SAMPLE_RATE) * frequency: 2.9663265306
```

In the following the corresponding curve is shown for different `N` using JFreeChart:

[image]

Comment: I tried your formula, but it comes out as having three constant repeating samples, (one for each second)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure what you mean. I have added to the answer the curves for various `N`-values (`1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, `16`) that illustrate the points generated by the formula and my implementation. Does it not work for you or are you looking for something else? Maybe some parameters are not defined in your code (I used the following parameters: `sampleLength = 500`, `ampLimit = 100.0`, `frequency = 261.63`, `SAMPLE_RATE = 44100.00` and `N = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16`). If you want, I can paste my code, maybe it will help to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to use sin to do this rather than produce the straight lines directly by a linear formula? There is an advantage in using sin in that you don't get harmonic distortion from aliasing, but if that's an issue then you can oversample. The issue is that sin is much slower than basic arithmetic.